# How to get data from all rxjs streams where one of them are not emitted?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some Rxjs streams that indicates changes:

```
reportChanges$
objectPropChanges$
textPropsChanges$
```

The first two have default values, the latest is not.

I tried to collect all changes and store them:

```
   this.changes$ = combineLatest([
            this.reportChanges$,
            this.objectPropChanges$,
            this.textPropsChanges$,
        ]).pipe(
            debounceTime(this.debouncetime),
            map(([reportProperties, reportObjectsProperties, textProperties]) => {
                return { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties, textProperties };
            }),
        );
```

Then to store it:

```
   this.changes$
            .pipe(
                skip(1),
                switchMap((properties: ReportPropertiesRequest) => this.save(this.registryId, properties)),
            )
            .subscribe();
    }
```

Issue is that `combineLatest` works only when all streams have the latest value. In my case `textPropsChanges$` has no.

How to collect all changes and store them?

My purpose is to collect all changes that happens asynchronously and store them imidiatly in storage.

Possible solution is set start value for all stremas with startWith or to use BehSubject. But in my case I can not use this, because user should make chnages himself.

Comment: Have you tried withLatestFrom rxjs operator?

Comment: No, I will try, but I think it awaits all streams data, is not?

Comment: I think if you use combineLatest along with withLatestFrom for each, it should work for you

Comment: you can "force" a fool value using `startWith` rxjs operator: `CombineLastest([this.reportChanges$.pipe(startWith(null)),this.objectPropsChanges$.pipe(startWith(null)),this.textPropsChanges$.pipe(startWith(null))])...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore some default token. So here I've used `null` as an example:

```ts
this.changes$ = combineLatest([
  this.reportChanges$,
  this.objectPropChanges$,
  this.textPropsChanges$.pipe(startWith(null)),
]).pipe(
  debounceTime(this.debouncetime),
  map(([reportProperties, reportObjectsProperties, textProperties]) => 
      textProperties != null ? // Only include if not null
      { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties, textProperties } : 
      { reportObjectsProperties, reportProperties }
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can have local object `changes = {}`. Then listen each stream separately and set chnages to this object:

```
this.reportChanges$.subscribe((data) => this.changes.report = data;
this.objectPropChanges$.subscribe((data) => this.changes.objectProp = data;
```